# asp.net website project not able to pickup namespaces from dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on moving appcode from a website project to a seperate dll, but after I have moved them and get it compiled, there are some frontend controls that reference classes in appcode not able to pick up the classes anymore after appcode is moved to anotehr dll, i needed to add a line on top of ascx files that says 
    <%@ Import Namespace="class.name" %>
in each and every single file that references the class, is tehre any better way? How come it doesn't automatically recognize the classes in dlls?

Comment: The namespace isn't in the form of "class.name". It's in the form of namespace.subnamespace. For example, you have a class called `MyNameSpace.MySubnamespace.MyClass`. The namespace to import would be `MyNameSpace.MySubnamespace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the web.config (See namespaces)

Example:

```
<system.web>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.IO" />
    <add namespace="System.Text" />
    <add namespace="Westwind.Utilities" />
    <add namespace="Westwind.Web.Controls" />
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="ww" namespace="Westwind.Web.Controls" assembly="Westwind.Web" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: what if its a user control that references the dll?

Comment: I would imagine it would work the same. You should not need to import the namespace on a page or user control.

Comment: This only works for the UI - if you are attempting to reference from .cs or .vb, it will not work

Comment: thanks, though moving appcode to another dll ended up with website building slower LOL